# Hyperlink not formatting properly in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub TxtBoxNotes_Change()
Dim Notes_Range As Range
Set Notes_Range = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A:A").Find(CStr(TxtBoxJobNumber.Value), [A100000], xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)
If Not Notes_Range Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("MAIN").Cells(Notes_Range.Row, "BC") = TxtBoxNotes.Text
    Sheets("MAIN").Cells(Notes_Range.Row, "BC").Activate
    'Add hyperlink
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E" & Notes_Range.Row).Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=Range("Main!" & "E" & Notes_Range.Row), _
    Address:="BC" & Notes_Range.Row
Else
    
End If
End Sub
```

My issue is this, when attempting to create a hyperlink to cells in column "E", I create the hyperlink from the UI it puts the full path as well as the cell and the hyperlink works. (See attached screencaps) From the VBA code it is missing the "spreadsheet" and Main" and just have part of the path and BC"X" X being the row.

I tried creating the URL manually from inside as follows:

```
Address:="https://ontivity.sharepoint.com/sites/Integrations/Shared Documents/Wireless Systems Integrator's/Integration Tracker.xlsm - Main!" & "BC" & Notes_Range.Row
```

And the URL looks correct but it still doesn't go to BC2 and opens chrome instead and tries to go to a invalid URL :([image: Try #3]

[image: What I am getting from the above code and a manual create from the UI.]

[image]

Comment: PS... Wanted to thank you in advance. Thought it would be like riding a cycle (10 years since I created my last app)

Comment: If you try recording a macro you will get something like: `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= "Main!A1", TextToDisplay:="Main!A1"`  Note `Address` vs `SubAddress` there...

Comment: That di the trick....

Answer (score 1):

From comment above:

```
Private Sub TxtBoxNotes_Change()
    Dim Notes_Range As Range, ws As Worksheet, txt As String
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN")
    txt = CStr(TxtBoxJobNumber.Value)
    Set Notes_Range = ws.Range("A:A").Find(txt, ws.Range("A100000"), _
                                      xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)
    If Not Notes_Range Is Nothing Then
        With Notes_Range.EntireRow
            .Columns("BC").Value = txt
            'use SubAddress
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Columns("E"), _
                  Address:="", SubAddress:=.Columns("BC").Address
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim... Full fix

```
Private Sub TxtBoxNotes_Change()
Dim Notes_Range As Range
Set Notes_Range = Sheets("MAIN").Range("A:A").Find(CStr(TxtBoxJobNumber.Value), [A100000], xlFormulas, xlPart, , xlNext)
If Not Notes_Range Is Nothing Then
    Sheets("MAIN").Cells(Notes_Range.Row, "BC") = TxtBoxNotes.Text
    Sheets("MAIN").Cells(Notes_Range.Row, "BC").Activate
    'Add hyperlink
    Worksheets("Main").Range("E" & Notes_Range.Row).Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=Range("Main!" & "E" & Notes_Range.Row), _
    Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="Main!BC" & Notes_Range.Row
Else
    
End If
End Sub
```